# Curl command ask for a token

Tags: curl, autodesk-forge, autodesk-inventor

Hi i'm doing the design automation and i have a second issue 
i already provided the token but it asking me again.

```
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/simple-introduction-design-automation-inventor
```

here the result:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your POST request is without header "-H 'Authorization: Bearer [token]".